# Automated Download: Can't get link from button

Tags: html, download, autoit

At work we have a tool created with autoit to download price lists from certain websites.
The tool opens an instance of internet explorer, goes to a given link, looks for a key (e.g.: ".xls") and then downloads the file.
Now, there is a [bulgarian website](http://portal.ncpr.bg/registers/pages/register/list-medicament.xhtml/)
which uses buttons for the downloads. (Button titled "Експорт на резултата")
The tool doesn't know how to handle buttons and I don't know how to implement such a feature. The easiest way for me  would be to get the link that the button refers to, which creates the file I want to download.
I tried looking at the source code of the button and the website, but couldn't find anything.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your file location to the `form` and the and a button to trigger the `form`

```
<form method="get" action="file.xls">
<button type="submit">Download!</button>
</form>
```